# Facebook: Import user wall post to native Android app

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, native

Is there an existing method that i am able to import a certain facebook user's wallpost to a native Android app?

I want to extract the schedules of blood donation drives from a blood donation facebook page to all of the users of my blood donation notifier app.

Hope to get some advice whether is it possible to do it without violating anything.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. No, you can't write a 100% native app to retrieve posts from Facebook.

Anyway, you can create an app for do what you want, but again, not native. For logging in and retrieving posts into and from Facebook you need the Facebook SDK and develop an app using that SDK, Android SDK doesn't have any class to handle Facebook requests (nor of any other social network for that matter).

I recommend you to go to developer.facebook.com.